# Преобразовать математическое выражение(string) в Bool c#

Tags: c#, строки, bool

У меня возникла проблема. Мне надо преобразовывать математические выражения в Bool.
Пример: У меня есть выражение строка "8+8=9", мне надо проверить правильность этого выражения. Мне надо как-то это строку представить так, чтобы я мог проверить правильность данного решения. Я пытался делать замену одного знака "=" в "==" ,но ничего не вышло... Очень важно, что может быть только строка. Есть ли какой-то способ проверять такие уравнения? Приведу еще пару примеров:

```
"3-5=2"  (false)
"10/2=5" (true)
"3+6=36" (false)
```

Уравнения простого типа "число1 действие(умножение, деление, вычитание, сложение) число2 = ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: работа примера]

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StringCulcUI");

        var mathExpressions = new string[] { "3-5=2", "10/2=5", "3+6=36" };
        List<(string, bool)> results = GetCheckResults(mathExpressions);

        results.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<(string, bool)> GetCheckResults(string[] mathExpressions)
    {
        var results = new List<(string, bool)>();
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        
        foreach (var exp in mathExpressions)
        {
            string[] subExps = exp.Split(new char[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int equals = int.Parse(dataTable.Compute(subExps[0], null).ToString());
            bool result = equals == int.Parse(subExps[1]);

            results.Add((exp, result));
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно просто `new DataTable().Compute("10/2=5", null)`. Для выражений со сравнениями функция `Compute` возвращает `true`/`false`.

Comment: @Antosha спасибо, буду знать

Comment: @Antosha куда вставить данный кусок кода? Можете , пожалуйста, написать?